# How does Emacs know what file I want to compile?

Tags: emacs, compilation

I use emacs for everything, and I often have a few different projects open in buffers in the background. Often, this involves having many files with the same name open (e.g. makefiles). When I `M-x compile` my current buffer, how does Emacs know what file I'm referring to?

For example, I'm working on a large project in SML. Compilation is kicked off by running `sml sources.cm`, which invokes the compilation manager. I have multiple `sources.cm` open, but Emacs selects the one in the right directory for the file that I'm dealing with, and it doesn't give me the option to `sml sources.cm<2>` even if I wanted to. At the same time, I can stay in my current buffer and call `M-x compile tsc App.ts` to kick off compilation for another project in Typescript that's in a completely different directory.

What environment does the `M-x compile` command operate in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each emacs buffer has its own [`default-directory`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Names.html) and that's where [`compile-command`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation.html) is executed.

Comment: Ah, I see it actually predicts less than I thought it did. That makes more sense. Thank you.